# No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

Why isn't a MultipartConfig annotation processor working on the annotated class? When I build my Java project with Gradle I get this warning: 
No processor claimed any of these annotations: `javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig,javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet`

And when I send a file to that servlet from a form I get

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /historyUpload/upload. Reason:

    Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Request.java:2279)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getPart(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:386)
    at com.mycom.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[...]
```

But I have javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar in my build.gradle - my project module includes several other HttpServlet classes that build and execute OK against it. That JAR does include javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig .

UploadServlet.java :

```
package com.mycom.uploadservlet;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp/upload", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, maxFileSize=1024*1024*50)
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        out.printf("Got part: name=%s, size=%d%n",req.getPart("file").getName(), req.getPart("file").getSize());

        int i=0;
        for(Part part: req.getParts())
        {
            out.printf("Got part: name=%s, size=%d%n",part.getName(), part.getSize());
            part.write(String.format("part-%02d.dat",i++));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I defined a `<servlet>` configuration in `web.xml` , that overrides the `@WebServlet()` annotation on the `class UploadServlet`. I didn't use an `@WebServlet` annotation, because I had the `<servlet>` configuration in `web.xml`. But that overriding also overrides any @MultipartConfig annotation on the `class UploadServlet`, even if no `<multipart-config>` block is included in the `<servlet>` block. So to process a form of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` either the `<servlet>` block in `web.xml` must include a `<multipart-config>` block, or no `<servlet>` block in `web.xml` and instead annotate the class with `@MultipartConfig()` (and so also `@WebServlet`).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycom.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```